# A placement code is saying that 'attempt to index nil with 'GetMouse'' and I have not got any variable codes after a code that needs it

Tags: lua, roblox

I have already tried the answer to one of my other questions but it didn't work. I'm quite new to Lua so maybe I'm missing something.

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local Mouse = player.GetMouse()
local Block = game.ServerStorage.Experimental

Mouse.Button1Down(place)

function place()
    Mouse.Hit.X = PosX
    Mouse.Hit.Y = PosY
    Mouse.Hit.Z = PosZ

    PlacedBlock = Block:Clone()
    PlacedBlock.Parent = game.Workspace
    PlacedBlock.Position = Vector3.new(PosX,PosY,PosZ)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple error here is you used `.` instead of `:` while calling `GetMouse()`. Once you replace that your code should work just fine :D

Answer (score 0):

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local Mouse = player:GetMouse()
local Block = game.ServerStorage.Experimental

function place()
    PlacedBlock = Block:Clone()
    PlacedBlock.Parent = workspace
    PlacedBlock.Position = Mouse.Hit.p
end

Mouse.MouseButton1Click:Connect(place)
```

This should work!

Comment: Unfortunately, the same error message has appeared. Do you know why that is? Maybe it is because of it being in the wrong place.                                                          game.StarterPack